# Can't Include winhttp.h (with code::blocks/mingw) c++

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I've been trying to include winhttp.h  and I get this error:

> Winhttp.h: No such file or directory

Mingw doesn't have it, how would I add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [runtime dynamic linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685090(VS.85).aspx) to link to the function(s) you want directly. You can't use the plain winhttp.h that ships with the Windows SDK because it contains Microsoft-specific features. You could also compile with Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition which would include the header you want.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I have copied the header from windows and it worked fine with the following addition:

```
#define __in
#define __out
#define __out_bcount(x)
#define __in_ecount(x)
#define __inout
#define __out_ecount_full_opt(x)
#define __in_opt
#define __out_data_source(x)
#include <winhttp.h>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Found a copy of `winhttp.h` here: https://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/technology/org.eclipse.higgins/trunk/app/org.eclipse.higgins.tcpserver/src/Third-party/VS2008/winhttp.h

Comment: Also, I found that I didn’t need the extra defines, I could just: `#include <specstrings.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. GET: https://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/technology/org.eclipse.higgins/trunk/app/org.eclipse.higgins.tcpserver/src/Third-party/VS2008/winhttp.h
2. `dlltool -z winhttp.def --export-all-symbol winhttp.dll`
3. `dlltool -k -d winhttp.def -l libwinhttp.a`
4. Link against the libwinhttp.a you just generated.